# Detect if an ELF binary was built with gprof instrumentation?

Tags: executable, elf, profiling

Is it possible to check if given program was compiled with GNU gprof instrumentation, i.e. with '-pg' flag passed to both compiler and linker, *without* running it to check if it would generate a `gmon.out` file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could check for references to function `mcount` (or possibly `_mcount` or `__mcount` according to [Implementation of Profiling](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/gprof/Implementation.html)). This function is necessary for profiling to work, and should be absent for non-profiled binaries.

Something like:

```
$ readelf -s someprog | egrep "\s(_+)?mcount\b" && echo "Profiling is on for someprog"
```

The above works on a quick test here.

Answer (score 2):

The regular expression in the answer above doesn't always work...but the general idea of grepping for "mcount" in the output of 'readelf -s [binary]' is correct, I think

Answer (score 1):

Adding more to the answers:

1. To check for instrumentation, grep for mcount/gmon:

   ```
   $  readelf -s <binary> | egrep "gmon|mcount"    
   20: 0000000000401160    63 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 __gmon_start__    
   28: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND mcount@GLIBC_2.2.5 (2)    
   36: 0000000000000000     0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS gmon-start.c    
   39: 00000000004011a0     0 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   12 call_gmon_start    
   100: 0000000000401160    63 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 __gmon_start__    
   114: 0000000000000000     0 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND mcount@@GLIBC_2.2.5
   ```
2. One needs to compile as well as link with `-pg` flags, otherwise `gmon.out` will not be generated. [stackoverflow link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088861/code-compiled-with-profiling-flag-does-not-generate-gmon-out)
3. I found that the binary on which I was running gprof didn't generate any  `gmon.out` file, despite compiling/linking with `-pg` flag. The reason being - I was killing my application, it wasn't a clean exit. `gprof` generates output only when the program exits normally. [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27747954/1755108)